# woocommerce wc_create_order(); is creating multiple orders instead of one?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

hello everyone I have been trying to use the `wc_create_order ();` function in woocommerce to create an order it works, but its creating more than one order.

[image]
 I tried a fresh install of WordPress with only the woocommerce plugin but the same issue how can I create only one order

the code i used:

```
   $productID=104;
My_create_order($productID);





 function My_create_order($productID) {


  global $woocommerce;

  $order = wc_create_order();

  $order->add_product( get_product( $productID), 1 ); 

  $order->calculate_totals();


}

add_action( 'init', 'My_create_order' );
```

and something else I noticed  when I add a product to an existing order like this

```
$myProduct = new WC_Product(104);

$order->add_product($myProduct, 1);
$order->calculate_totals();
```

it's also adding the product multiple times!!

[image]

also tried using a different way

```
$order_data = array(
    'post_name'     => 'order-test' ,
    'post_type'     => 'shop_order',
    'post_title'    => 'order-tests ', 
    'post_status'   => 'wc-completed',
    'ping_status'   => 'closed',    

);

// create order
$order_id = wp_insert_post( $order_data, true );
```

and like this

```
    if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {

$order=My_create_order();


}


add_action('init', 'My_create_order');



 function My_create_order() {


  global $woocommerce;

  $order = wc_create_order();



return $order;
}
```

but the same issue

[image]

Comment: edit the question to show all the code you tried and all results of debugging.

Comment: `init` is fired on every HTTP request and this include AJAX calls. on which conditions do you wan to create this order ?

Comment: i created a simple form for the user when he submit it i want to add the order

Comment: then you have to test if the submit button of the form is submitted like `if (isset($_POST["buttonName"])) { // create order ...}`

Comment: same issue the order is added more than one time     if (isset($_POST["myBtn"]){
$order=My_create_order();
}

Comment: thank you mmm very much it worked but can you explain for me why it did not work before or just a hint so i can understand what was the issue

Answer (score 1):

thank you `mmm` it worked i just missed an ``

```
    if (isset($_POST["myBtn"])) 

      {  $order=My_create_order();

      }
```

---

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'My_create_order');



 function My_create_order() {


  global $woocommerce;

  $order = wc_create_order();



return $order;
}
```